# Display a text message if the field is not found and not if found

Tags: plugins, php, functions

I am trying to display a message like "Sorry no information here" if a field is not found and if field is found, no message should appear. I am using the ACF plugin for displaying fields on the front end in a user profile.

This is my code:

```
<?php $user_ID = get_current_user_id(); 

            $label = 'user_' . $user_ID;
            the_field('Information', $label); ?>
```

If anyone has an idea, I have tried a lot of things but nothing helps. Thanks in advance. Nico

***Update: In fact, with ACF plugin for wordpress, I have created a field to display in user account in the backend of wordpress. So now I want to display this field (information) in the frontend account of the user.

If I need to put a message for my client, I put this message in the wordpress backend user account.

So in the frontend account, if I don't have put any message in this field (information), I want to display an automatic message like: "You don't have information yet"

If I put a message in the field (information) in the wordpress backend user account, I want the automatic message disappear and my message is displayed.


for now the message I put in field (information) in the backend account user is displayed correctly in the frontend user account  ***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you just looking for a simple if then statement?  Assuming that your fields are set up properly, then this code should work:

```
<?php 
    $user_ID = get_current_user_id(); 
    $label = 'user_' . $user_ID;

    if (get_field('Information', $label)) {
      //there is data;
    } else { 
      echo 'Sorry no information here';
    }
?>
```

Comment: Nothing appears, same if information field is empty or not, no echo and no information are displayed

Comment: try adding an echo to replace the line `//there is data`.  You should get something one way or another.  That statement is either true or false.

Comment: Yes it works ! I have already try but I put a syntax error so thank you for all my friend!

Answer (score 2):

`the_field()` echos the field value, while `get_field()` returns the field value which can be checked using `if` statement to display a message. [**Documentation**](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/)

```
<?php 

$user_ID = get_current_user_id(); 

$label = 'user_' . $user_ID;

//the_field('Information', $label);

if (! get_field('Information', $label)) {

      echo 'Sorry no information here';

    } 
?>
```

Comment: echo always display, if information field is empty or have content

Comment: Yes, `the_field('Information', $label);` is equivalent to `echo get_field('Information', $label);`

Answer (score 0):

I finally find the solution, thanks you Rudtek, and thank you Qaisar Feroz for all of your time and code.

So this is the working code:

```
<?php 
    $user_ID = get_current_user_id(); 
    $label = 'user_' . $user_ID;

    if (get_field('information', $label)) {
      //there is data;
      echo get_field('galerie', $label);
    } else { 
      echo 'Sorry no information here';
    }
?>
```